# how to check a file is completely uploaded in azure file share froma zure file sync

Tags: synchronization, azure-files

I have a file share to which the entry point is form azure file sync. How to check if a file completely copied (around 2 gb) to file share from azure file sync?

And then I have to copy this to the other folder in the same share. I am using startcopy and checking status with `file.copystatus` but I always get `success` and copy completes within seconds. I am checking this in a console app as of now.

I have tried to check the last modified date of the file in the source file share and if it is less than the current time -1 then only uploading to dest file share as of now but this is not the correct way in my opinion. What is the optimal way to do it?

Comment: Can someone please throw light on this?

Comment: Did you get solution for this?